# UICollectionView bounces to the very top part when scrolled all the way to the bottom

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I added this code

`self.myCollectionView.contentOffset.y = (50.0)`

which works as intended. But whenever the UICollectionView scrolls to the very bottom; it bounces back to the contentOffset scroll position.

Comment: Bounces back how? My immediate idea is that your ScrollView isn't large enough.

Comment: UICollectionView automatically has scroll capability, and you know how the view bounces when it's scrolled to the very bottom or when view was pulled to refresh? That was the bounce that I was saying.

Now the problem is that whenever I scroll the collection view down to the very bottom it bounces all the way up.

Comment: Yes, it (and UITableView) has a scroll view, but if the UIScrollView's size is smaller than the size of the fully-displayed CollectionView, you get a bouncing animation when you get to the bottom of the scroll view, even if there are more cells to display. It bouncing to the top is not behavior I've seen before, so I may not be able to help. :(

Comment: where have you added this code?

Comment: Hey, come to think of it. I placed the code inside func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

I moved the code right before I call the collectionView.reloadata(), and that solved the bounce offset issue.